# Function executing instantly, not waiting for setTimeout

Tags: javascript, multithreading, function

I would like to disable my dropdown while my while Colors(interval) is firing. In my case I manually set a cutoff after 5 seconds. What I'm experiencing is that when I place the re-activator in my case block, it does not wait for the setTimeout. Or are both calls firing at the same time and so while the setTimeout is firing (aka waiting those five seconds) the next call (the re-activator) fires as well?

The other question —and the reason I wanted to deactivate the dropdown while the my Colors is firing —is that I noticed that while the Colors was firing, if I clicked on the dropdown again —aka to fire off another call to it, the second call would result in Colors endlessly firing (assuming an infinite loops created somehow). Thoughts on why?

```
 function timeToHexColor(){
    var time = new Date();
    var timestamp = time.toString("hh:mm:ss");
    document.getElementById("board").innerHTML += 
                              "#" + timestamp.split(":").join("") + "<br/>";   
}

function Colors(interval) {
    this.interval = interval;
    switch (this.interval) {
        case 'second': 
            document.getElementById('options').disabled = true;
            x = setInterval(timeToHexColor,1000);
            setTimeout(stopColors, 5000);
            //Placing the re-activtor here executes instantly not after the setTimeout.
            //document.getElementById('options').disabled = false;
            break;
        case 'minute': 
            x = setInterval(timeToHexColor,60000);
            setTimeout(stopColors, 5000);
            document.getElementById('options').disabled = true;
            break;       
        case 'hour': 
            x = setInterval(timeToHexColor,60000*60);
            setTimeout(stopColors, 5000);
            document.getElementById('options').disabled = true;
            break;
        case 'day': 
            x = setInterval(timeToHexColor,60000*1440);
            setTimeout(stopColors, 5000);
            document.getElementById('options').disabled = true;
            break;
        default: 
    }
}

function stopColors() {
    clearInterval(x);
    //Placing the re-activator here instead works they way I intended,
    //after the repeat cycle is finished.
    document.getElementById('options').disabled = false;

}
$("#options").prop('selectedIndex',-1);
$("#options").change(function() {
  Colors('second');
});
```

Comment: you need to enable the "options" in your stopColors function. otherwise it is not possible

Comment: `javascript` and `multithreading` tags in one question, something you don't see every day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're expecting `setTimeout` to pause code execution. That's not what `setTimeout` does. It schedules the function you pass to it to execute at a later time and returns immediately.

If you want to structure you code so that the reactivator is located near the switch statement rather than `stopColors` use an anonymous function:

```
document.getElementById('options').disabled = true;
 x = setInterval(timeToHexColor,1000);
 setTimeout(function(){
     stopColors();
     document.getElementById('options').disabled = false;
 }, 5000);
```

You will notice that this is exactly the same as putting the reactivator inside `stopColors` with the exception that now it is not hardcoded in `stopColors` (potentially making the function more reusable?). So it's basically a style issue of where you want the reactivator code to be. The mechanism behind `setTimeout` still works the same.

Do note that javascript is single threaded. Which is why functions like `setTimeout` and `XMLHTTPrequest` behave the way they do - continuing execution of javascript until the end of script and then at some later the browser will execute the given function. If you try to pause execution then the browser will not be given processing time to do things like draw to screen or accept user clicks or download ajax response.

Comment: Thanks for the note slebetman, probably a very crazy thought, but I was under the impression that the 'scheduling' itself was the the execution of the sitTimeout function and thus the scheduling itself was a process.